# OpenCV algorithm output index

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv

I am using OpenCV goodFeaturesToTrack algorithm to identify features for Lucas Kanade tracker to use. Then I compare results from the tracker with ground truth data at same points in the image. When I unpack ground truth data, upper left point coordinate is (1,1).

My question is what is the convention that OpenCV goodFeaturesToTrack algorithm output uses - is the upper left corner coordinate (0,0) or (1,1)?

Comment: I can't see a reason why it should be (1,1). Usually is (0,0). Does your ground truth come from Matlab (which is 1-based)?

Comment: Yes it does, which would cause false comparison if everything in openCV is (0,0) based but it would make sense for openCV to do that since C++ stores data in this way. Just want to be sure to eliminate that as source of problems.

Comment: Just shift your C++ rectangle by (1,1) and you can then compare them: `cv::Rect r = ...; r += cv::Point(1,1);`